# SSH setting a timeout for the 'password' prompt?

Tags: bash, ssh

Is there an SSH option (similar to `-o ConnectTimeout=$seconds`) that limits the time that it spends waiting at a `password:` prompt?

Note, I **do** use keypairs for passwordless ssh, but I still wind up seeing a `password:` prompt several times a week, 
because I have bash functions running in a background window that reconnect my SSH tunnels whenever they drop (as I wander between WiFi networks and close the MacBook lid randomly).  So sometimes SSH negotiation can get into the "password:" state, then it *stays* there until I manually intervene with `^C` or `killall ssh`...

```
dtunnel-home () {
  while true ; do
    title "XXX-TTT-..."
    wait-for-host.sh "$g"   ## sleep until ping-able.
    time (
        set -x
         ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10        \
             -Y -L 5920:$t:5900  -L ...  \
             $g_user@$g
    ) ; date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar problem (a cygwin ssh shell running in the background that should reconnect automatically, where sometimes a password prompt appears).

I did find a solution in the *ssh_config* man page:

```
BatchMode=yes
```

or as a parameter for the ssh shell:

```
-o BatchMode=yes
```

according to the man page it disables the password prompt client side:

> If set to “yes”, passphrase/password querying will be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

For linux you maybe have the option to workaround with the `timeout` command, provided with 
"coreutils" from any regular RPMs .

If it's timeout then return code 124

```
cinacio@jdivm04:~> time timeout 10s ssh cinacio@vulca_5 ; echo $?
cinacio@vulca_5's password:

real    0m10.002s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.002s

124
```

I discovery this at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785832/how-to-make-ssh-command-execution-to-timeout

Comment: Hmmm, that will timeout the entire SSH session, so in my case that will kill the tunnel after the 10s timeout even if it did sucessfully connect and login normally with pubkeys.  Also I'd really prefer something portable (no `timeout` on MacOSX).

Comment: ...but further down in the same StackOverflow answer I found `PasswordAuthentication=no` which completely prevents the `password:` prompt that was plaguing me!

Comment: @DouglasDD I understand that you're showing appreciation, but you really shouldn't have this as the accepted answer; the limitation you've described in your comment makes it useless, even though you have (separately) found a workaround for your particular workflow.